# Windows Backup to wait for Backup-Target-HDD

Tags: windows-7, backup

I'm currently using the built in backup function of Windows 7 (Pro) to do a file backup (not an image). However when I forget to plug-in the external HDD where the backup should be written to, I get a warning in the Message Center like one day *after* the backup failed.

Is there a way to get a proper notification that gives me the chance to plug-in the HDD before the backup starts?